# is there a way to apply changes in browser inspector to CSS files synchronously?

Tags: css, visual-studio, inspector, browser-link

I was wondering if there is a way to synchronously apply changes made in the inspector to CSS elements to the actual CSS files in visual studio. It would save a lot of time it this would be available.

Comment: change your actual css and refresh the webpage!  You shouldn't be doing your developing in the inspector - if you have changed so many styles you can't remember what you've changed, then there's something wrong there

Comment: @Pete yes, I'm doing this already, but I was wondering if there were a shortcut.

Comment: If that's what you're doing then you shouldn't need what you're asking for - inspect element is mainly for seeing what styles are currently applied and seeing how minor tweeks may affect things - it shouldn't be used for wholesale changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the browser link feature in web essentials.

> When making edits in the various browser's developer tools, you can click Save F12 changes to automatically transfer the changes back to their source files in Visual Studio. This works with CSS changes only.

http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink

Comment: I think this feature is removed from vs2017, am I right?